# Solving First Order PDE with Characteristics Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let the first order PDE: $$u_t+au_x=b-cu$$
I tried Characterestics method:
$\frac{dt}{ds}=1$ and $\frac{dx}{ds}=a$ and $\frac{du}{ds}=b-cu$

Then we have if we suppose that $t(0)=0$, then we'll have $t=s$ and $x(t)=a.t+x(0)$

But I could not solve the last ode.

Comment: Shouldn't your equation read $u_t+au_x=b-cu$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks.  I should post an answer before too long.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "last equation" is

$\dfrac{du}{ds} = b - cu, \tag 1$

which may be written as

$\dfrac{du}{ds} + cu = b; \tag 2$

this is a first order, linear, constant-coefficient ODE, the solution of which is well-known; indeed, we may derive it in short order here; we multiply (2) through by $e^{cs}$:

$e^{cs}\dfrac{du}{ds} + ce^{cs}u = be^{cs}, \tag 3$

and note that

$\dfrac{d}{ds}(e^{cs}u) = e^{cs}\dfrac{du}{ds} + ce^{cs}u; \tag 4$

thus, (3) becomes

$\dfrac{d}{ds}(e^{cs}u) = be^{cs}, \tag 5$

which may readily be integrated 'twixt $0$ and $s$:

$e^{cs}u(s) - u(0) = \displaystyle \int_0^s \dfrac{d}{dr}(e^{cr}u(r)) \; dr = b \int_0^s e^{cr} \; dr = \dfrac{b}{c}(e^{cs} - 1); \tag 6$

thus,

$e^{cs}u(s) = u(0) + \dfrac{b}{c}(e^{cs} - 1), \tag 7$

and

$u(s) = u(0)e^{-cs} +  \dfrac{b}{c}(1 - e^{-cs}) = (u(0) - \dfrac{b}{c})e^{-cs} + \dfrac{b}{c}.  \tag 8$

***We check:***

differentiating (8),

$\dfrac{du(s)}{ds} = -c  (u(0) - \dfrac{b}{c})e^{-cs}  = -c((u(0) - \dfrac{b}{c})e^{-cs} + \dfrac{b}{c}) + b = -cu(s) + b, \tag 9 $

in light of (8).  This is then the required solution to (2).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\frac{du}{ds}+cu=e^{-cs}\frac{d}{ds}(ue^{cs})
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$u_t+au_x=b-cu$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic system : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{du}{b-cu}$ .

A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{a}$ :
$$x-at=C_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{b-cu}\quad$  after solving :
$$\left(u-\frac{b}{c}\right)e^{c\,t}=C_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $C_2=F(C_1)$ is :
$$\left(u-\frac{b}{c}\right)e^{c\,t}=F(x-at)$$
with arbitrary function $F$.

Or equivalently on explicit form : $$\quad u(x,t)=\frac{b}{c}+e^{-c\,t}F(x-at)$$
The arbitrary function $F$ has to be determined according to some specified boundary and/or initial condition.

What is the condition which allows to determine the function $F$ ?

In the wording of the question it is written : "Then we have if we suppose that $t(0)=0$ ". This is not clear. Is it a specification or is it a supposition ? Moreover there is no condition. Thus as the problem is presently raised they are an infinity of solutions :
$$\boxed{ u(x,t)=\frac{b}{c}+e^{-c\,t}F(x-at)\qquad\text{any function }F .}$$
If you put this result into the PDE you will see that it agrees.